# How do I set the R, G, B and Alpha components of a color?

Tags: java, image, rgb, rgba

There are 3 integer values that makes up a RGB value, and also i have the Alpha component value of the color. how do i set these 4 values to get the desired colour

Comment: Set these values in what context? what API, the `Color` class?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create a [`Color`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) object (the values should either be [`int`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) between `0`-`255` or [`float`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) between `0f`-`1f`:

```
Color c = new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
```

---

If you want to paint an image with that color:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics(); 
graphics.setColor(c);
graphics.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
graphics.dispose();
```

If you only want to set a pixel (color model must be ARGB):

```
image.setRGB(50, 50, c.getRGB());
```

Comment: How do i change the already set RGBA values?. Is there a `c.setRGB(red,green,blue,alpha)` function?

Comment: `setRGB(x, y, rgba)` takes an integer composite of red, green, blue and _alpha_. Create the color with transparency using `rgba = new Color(r, g, b, alpha).getRGB()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
panel1.setBackground(new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.5f));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also  use

```
int colorToSet = Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue); to set Alpha
```