# Changing alpha of rgb bit

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, alpha, rgba

I am setting alpha of rgb of buffredimage in java.
This code changes alpha value but i can't retrieve the same value after saving the file.
How to overcome this problem.

```
// ================ Code for setting alpha ===============
int alpha=140;
// alpha value to set in rgb

int b=alpha<<24;
b=b|0x00ffffff;

ialpha.setRGB(0, 0,ialpha.getRGB(0, 0)&b);
// ialpha is a bufferedimage of type TYPE_INT_ARGB

ImageIO.write(ialpha, "png", new File("C:/newimg.png"));
System.out.println("\nFile saved !");

// ================ Code for getting alpha ===============

int val=(ialpha.getRGB(0, 0)&0xff000000)>>24;
if(val<0)
val=256+val;
System.out.println("Returned alpha value:"+val);
```

This just returns 255 as alpha value. it does not return value i set i.e 140.

Please help me to retrieve alpha value i previously set.

Comment: why you use bit operation?? java has some beautiful features to get set rgb create new color and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734171/set-rgb-and-alpha-component-value-of-a-color?rq=1). You may find what u looking for in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the code for getting the alpha. In the second bit shift operation, you don't take the sign bit into consideration.

```
int val=(ialpha.getRGB(0, 0) & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

This will give the value `0xffffff8c` (given your initial alpha of `140` of `0x8c`).
See [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for more detail. In particular:

> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

You need to either do either:

```
int val = (ialpha.getRGB(0, 0) & 0xff000000) >>> 24; // shift zero into left
```

Or:

```
int val = ialpha.getRGB(0, 0) >> 24) & 0xff; // mask out the sign part
```

PS: I tend to prefer the latter, because most people (myself included) never remember what the `>>>` operator actually does.. ;-)