# How can I change the transparent PNG image color?

Tags: java, image, colors, png

From [this page](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-11.0/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/overscroll_glow.png)

[image]

That's the image in which I want to change color.

How to change PNG image color white to red in Java?

Comment: Change it where? How are you displaying this image? If you want to display it with a red background, simply display it on a component with a red background.

Comment: Do you mean you want to read a image and then create another image but change the white colour to a red colour inside java?

Comment: Huh? The transparent part doesn't have a colour - it's transparent. If you want a different colour to show through the transparent pixels, simply put the image on top of another image the colour you want to show through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What framework/library are you using? Check for a function to parse the file into a data structure. Once that is done you should be able to change the alpha component of the data structure in order to set the transparency. java.awt.Color is one class which supports this.

Some references (found via google):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing
- [How do I set the R, G, B and Alpha components of a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734171/set-rgb-and-alpha-component-value-of-a-color)
- http://graphics.wikia.com/wiki/Alpha_blending
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible with GLSL , or some other high-level library